# how to fire bullet in pygame (not OOP)

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code right now.

```
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

enemy_start_x = -200
enemy_start_y = random.randrange(0,470)
enemy_speed = 3

while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quitgame()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = -5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            print(">Bullet Fire!<")
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quitgame()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0

x += x_change
gameDisplay.fill(white)

gameDisplay.blit(enemyImg,(enemy_start_x,enemy_start_y))
enemy_start_x += enemy_speed

gameDisplay.blit(playerImg,(x,y))

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

I have player moving left and right, enemy move above him from left to right and speeding up in every circle.
What i need to do is when press up key i want to shoot bullet.

Comment: also i have more global variables that i didn't mention here, like screen setup, loading images and other.

Comment: Do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want it to print it out?

Comment: OOP is rather simple to implement in python. If you try and tackle the problem head on you'll get better results in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use OOP , you can use a tuple to express a bullet like `((pos_x , pos_y) , (speed_x,speed_y))` or some structs like that .

Keep all bullets in a list `bullets_list`.

When you press `UP` , you can create a bullet that in same position of your player with specific speed .

In every frame flush , you need to loop over the `bullets_list` to modify the `(pos_x , pos_y)` according to the `(speed_x , speed_y)` , and check if the distance between bullet and enemy is close enough .

OOP will do this job better if you regrade bullet as a object and call it `move` method you implement .

Comment: i'm novice with programming language i just started month ago OOP in java, just understand basic concepts

Comment: @RedIcon Just go ahead , OOP is good part of Program Language to learn . There is a small project of me of pygame without OOP https://github.com/KIDJourney/Sokoban_Pygame